# Loading a viewcontroller underneath the current viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

Is this even possible? I have 3 UIViewControllers: The main screen (A), the screen the user tapped a button to get to (B), and the login screen (C). If the user isn't logged in, it will go from A -> C and when they log in it should go from C -> B but I need to present B underneath C and before C is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

You can present a view controller modally with no animation.

```
[self presentViewController:viewControllerC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

You can do this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` which means your login view controller will appear right after launch. And then when the user has successfully logged in, you simply call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

on the C view controller (or whichever one is the login one) and it slides down to reveal the main application. It's a cool effect. You can also choose to change the transition style of the view controller to have it flip around horizontally to reveal the app after a login, etc.

```
viewControllerC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the UIViews of the button and login screen from main screen you can do [self.view sendSubViewToBack:subview];

Comment: Is there something similar to this that can be accessed from self (UIViewController) instead of UIView?

Comment: No, because what you see on the screen is the UIView of the ViewController, the VC itself is a combination of the View and Controller in a MVC development environment. So what I do is have a main VC, then load other VC's into that as/if needed and manage those VC.views from the first VC.

Answer (score 0):

You could present C in a modal view from A
And Push B before dismissing C.
That's if you want to use a modal presentation of C (which seems better to me).

Even if it's not the case, you could still change the viewControllers of the navigationController just after C appeared or just before it start disappearing.